# How to spoof complete browser identity?

Tags: browser, spoofing

I found question on how to spoof user agent. I dont' want to spoof only user agent. I want to spoof everything from user agent, to Accept headers to http headers and also the information javascript can tell about browser - screen resolution and depth, class cpu, platform, device name, etc.

Do you know of a way to achieve this in any browser out there ? I don't want 10 plugins to achieve this. I'd like unified way.

Comment: If you want to do this in a really stealthy way, this is going to be difficult. Each browser has obvious, and then more subtle behaviors, that a page either rely on, or actively check for, especially in the JS space. I think your best bet would be to try to find a way to automate various browsers to do whatever testing you want. Otherwise you could check out Opera which has settings to "mask as" Internet Explorer or Firefox, which supposedly does more than just change the user agent, but I'm unsure exactly what.

Comment: from your comment, I'm unsure if I communicated what i need clearly now. I don't need to change only user agent and "acting browser" but also other parameters and emulating different users coming from different platforms, devices, screen resolutions, etc.

Comment: I don't know if it's important that this is done by a local app that does spoofing, but have you considered a page that offers remote browser screenshots, such as http://browsershots.org/? (There's lots more sites like this.) This would give you both a screenshot and a bunch of requests.

Comment: that's interesting, but charged for what I really need to achieve. I need another layer above browser's parameters to emulate those parameters

Comment: What are you really trying to do? What's your end goal?

Comment: @HairOfTheDog Which part should i clarify ? I gave a good description of what i need, didn't I?

Comment: @Greenleader Are you trying to simulate testing your web site with different browsers?

Comment: yes, however I am not going to to this with external service as suggested before. I'd rather do it locally. It is possible it's not an option without a custom software though as I am researching this idea now... :(

Comment: @Greenleader As I was researching about this I noticed that the information is not consolidated under one library, even more some `callbacks` are dependant on browser and even on mobile. Eg.- You even can get battery info on some mobiles(not ios). I believe you would need to make a "layer".